# Getting results of H2O neural nets from: h2o.grid.grid_search.H2OGridSearch

Tags: python-3.x, h2o

I have been training a neural net with hyperparameters but am unable get results out as I am getting the following error message.
nn

Error message: 'int' object is not iterable

Code:

```
      nn = H2OGridSearch(model=H2ODeepLearningEstimator,
                                   hyper_params = {
            'activation' :[ "Rectifier","Tanh","Maxout","RectifierWithDropout","TanhWithDropout","MaxoutWithDropout"],
            'hidden':[[20,20],[50,50],[30,30,30],[25,25,25,25]],            ## small network, runs faster
            'epochs':1000000,                      ## hopefully converges earlier...
            'rate' :[0.0005,0.001,0.0015,0.002,0.0025,0.003,0.0035,0.0040,0.0045,0.005],
            'score_validation_samples':10000,      ## sample the validation dataset (faster)
            'stopping_rounds':2,
            'stopping_metric':"misclassification", ## alternatives: "MSE","logloss","r2"
            'stopping_tolerance':0.01})
nn.train(train1_x, train1_y,train1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a slight problem with how you are defining the grid.  You can only pass a dictionary of lists (of values to grid over for each hyperparamter) in the `hyper_params` argument.  The reason you are seeing the `Error message: 'int' object is not iterable` error message is because you are trying to pass an integer instead of a list for both `score_validation_samples` and `stopping_rounds`.

If there are arguments that you don't intend to grid over, then they should be passed instead to the grid's `train()` method.  I'd also recommend using a validation frame or cross-validation when doing grid search so you don't have to use training metrics to choose the best model.  See example below.

```
import h2o
from h2o.estimators.deeplearning import H2ODeepLearningEstimator
from h2o.grid.grid_search import H2OGridSearch
h2o.init()

# Import a sample binary outcome training set into H2O
train = h2o.import_file("https://s3.amazonaws.com/erin-data/higgs/higgs_train_10k.csv")

# Identify predictors and response
x = train.columns
y = "response"
x.remove(y)

# For binary classification, response should be a factor
train[y] = train[y].asfactor()

# Execute a grid search (also do 5-fold CV)
grid = H2OGridSearch(model=H2ODeepLearningEstimator, hyper_params = {
            'activation' :["Rectifier","Tanh","Maxout","RectifierWithDropout","TanhWithDropout","MaxoutWithDropout"],
            'hidden':[[20,20],[50,50],[30,30,30],[25,25,25,25]]})
grid.train(x=x, y=y, training_frame=train, \
           score_validation_samples=10000, \
           stopping_rounds=2, \
           stopping_metric="misclassification", \
           stopping_tolerance=0.01, \
           nfolds=5)

# Look at grid results
gridperf = grid.get_grid(sort_by='mean_per_class_error')
```

There are more examples of how to use grid search in the [H2O Python Grid Search tutorial](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/blob/master/h2o-open-tour-2016/chicago/grid-search-model-selection.ipynb).